# How to add links and change structure of Jekyll website

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to get a personal website up using Jekyll, and initially it seemed fairly easy. However, every time I make changes to the index.html file in the _site folder, I end up losing them since Jekyll rebuilds that folder every time `jekyll serve` is run.

I'm using the Academic theme, and I'm trying to add nav-bar links to my projects and the like, but those keep getting reset along with my index.html file. I'm sure this is a fairly easy fix, but could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it. You just pull the index.html file out of the _site folder, edit it, and run `jekyll build`.

Comment: That is *not* the way to do this. You should never edit files in the `_site` directory. That is your build output. You should edit your source files only. In the case of navigation that is commonly done in a `_data/navigation.yml` file or in the `_layouts/default.html` file.